# How to compare against an empty NSArray showing <null>

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements, nsarray

I'm doing some validation and can't seem to get what should be a simple conditional right

my method has an arg of NSArray and when I NSLog it out I get the following

```
"var was <null>"
```

Yet when I do something like the below It always returns YES / TRUE

```
if (array != nil) {

}
```

this also fails

```
if (array != NULL) {

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it actually contains `[NSNull null]`. Plain old `nil` is logged as (null).